# Add items to a collection from children classes

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I have an Abstract class (RandomEvent) which contains an Hashmap (the sampleSpace with sample measure). This Hashmap has to be populated in the children classes.
Is there a way to make it visible and editable only in the children class but NOT in the same package where i put the Abstract class?
It seem to me that this can't be solved using only the java class... maybe there is some pattern?
This is what i did:

```
public abstract class RandomVariable<Sample> {

    private final Hashtable<Sample, Integer> sampleSpace;
    private boolean setted;

    public RandomVariable() {
        sampleSpace = new Hashtable<>();

        setted = false;
        setSampleSpace();
        setted = true;
    }

    public Sample fireEvent() {
        //return one sample chosen randomly according to the probability measure
    }

    protected Map<Sample, Integer> getSampleSpace() {
        if(setted==true) {
            Map<Sample, Integer> ret = new Hashtable<>();
            ret.putAll(sampleSpace);
            return ret;
        }
        return sampleSpace;
    }

    protected abstract void setSampleSpace(); 

    public double getProbability(final Set<Sample> subset) {
        //return probability of a subset of the sample space
    }

    public double getProbability(Sample sample) {
        //return probability a the sample
    }

    public boolean isSetted() {
        return setted;
    }
}
```

So the setSampleSpace() method has to be implemented in the children classes that will define a concrete random event (with a precise sample set).
Here an example:

```
public class Coin extends RandomVariable<String> {
    @Override
    protected void setSampleSpace() {
        if(!isSetted()) {
            super.getSampleSpace().put("head", 1);
            super.getSampleSpace().put("back", 1);
        }
    }
}
```

In c++ i would have just declared the Hashmap as protected, but i'm studing java now and it seems that there are some differences in the access modifiers.
Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably have the child classes populate the `Map` with initial data, then save the reference to that `Map` as an unmodifiable map. This should help get rid of your `setted` variable.

```
public abstract class RandomVariable<Sample> {
    private final Map<Sample, Integer> sampleSpace;

    public RandomVariable() {
        Map<Sample, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        populateSampleSpace(map);
        this.sampleSpace = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    protected abstract void populateSampleSpace(Map<Sample, Integer> sampleSpace);
}
```

Then a child class would only have to add data into the `Map` that is provided to `populateSampleSpace()`, and the parent class could ensure that after the data is populated, that `sampleSpace` cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve that is to make a subpackage for your abstract class and its implementation. For example :

```
org.example.application.random.RandomVariable
org.example.application.random.impl.Coin
```

Then when using these classes from outside their packages you will get the level of encapsulation of your API that you want.